# add and remove spinner dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, removechild

Hi I have created a layout which contains two buttons add and remove, when i click on the plus button it will add a spinner pro-grammatically and i have another button (remove) with - sign as you can see in the picture , now i want when i click to the remove button it will delete the spinner from last, please guide me how can i delete the spinner? i have add the spinner pro-grammatically and it is creating spinner pro-grammatically. i'll post my code.
[image]

```
public class AddMenulist extends Fragment{

    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;
    Button bt1 , bt2;
    LinearLayout linearlayout,linearlayout1;

    ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
     private Spinner spinner;
     private Spinner spinner2;

    public AddMenulist(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);

        tv1 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        tv2 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.userName2);

        bt1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        bt2 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

        linearlayout = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        spinnerArray.add("one");
        spinnerArray.add("two");
        spinnerArray.add("three");
        spinnerArray.add("four");
        spinnerArray.add("five");

       bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {




            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                linearlayout1 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                linearlayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
                linearlayout1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams );


                tv3 = new TextView(getActivity());
                tv3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                tv3.setText("Label");

                tv4 = new TextView(getActivity());
                tv4.setText("Category");




                spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);

                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                spinner2 = new Spinner(getActivity());
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);

                spinner2.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter2);

                linearlayout1.addView(tv3);
                linearlayout1.addView(spinner);

                linearlayout1.addView(tv4);
                linearlayout1.addView(spinner2);
                linearlayout.addView(linearlayout1);


            }
        });

       bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Comment: You did not tried removed functionality ? OR currently it removed from first ?

Comment: try this : `linearlayout1.removeView(view)`

Comment: ok i'll try that one.

Comment: it is working but it is removing the last spinners and the two labels only , i want to remove both spinners and two text view one by one from the last , it is removing the last two labels and last two spinners . i have used this code.
linearlayout1.removeView(spinner);
          
linearlayout1.removeView(tv3);
          
linearlayout1.removeView(spinner2);
          linearlayout1.removeView(tv4);

Comment: means i have to count all the spinners on remove button and then i can remove it, how can do this ?

Comment: you should fragment the views accordingly, use separate layouts which houses items which are supposed to be volatile. That will help in managing what is to be shown, hidden etc. this way you can empty the content if you want to vanish it, inflate and populate it back.. probably group 2 or 3 items in a layout which are suppose to vanish together or appear together

Comment: Let me explain my issue. I added 4 spinners by clicking Add button 4 times. Now I'm clicking remove button. It removes only the last spinners . Remaining 3 spinners still exist.Now when i again click to remove button it remove the spinners from the renaming three n now we have 2 spinners left and so on. Is there anyway to remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this
yourSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: i used this linearlayout1.removeView(view) , it is working but it is removing the last spinners and the two labels only , i want to remove both spinners and two text view one by one from the last , it is removing the last two labels and last two spinners . i have used this code. linearlayout1.removeView(spinner); linearlayout1.removeView(tv3); linearlayout1.removeView(spinner2); linearlayout1.removeView(tv4);

Comment: What do you want to do?Remove first two spinners and textviews or last ones?.What do you mean by one by one.please explain

Comment: i have label and spinner again label and spinner horizontally  in linear layout as you can see in my code  and in pic. when i click to remove button i want to remove the two text views and the two spinners from last one buy one i have used this code but it is removing the last two text view and two spinners which are horizontally.
linearlayout1.removeView(spinner);
          linearlayout1.removeView(tv3);
          linearlayout1.removeView(spinner2);
          linearlayout1.removeView(tv4);

Comment: i mean i have click to + button it will add the two text view with two spinners horizontally, as you see in the pic, suppose i have clicked 4 times and it will create the 4 views as i created in screen shot now when click to the - button it will remove the last views and it i click again it will remove the again view

Comment: Let me explain my issue. I added 4 spinners by clicking Add button 4 times. Now I'm clicking remove button. It removes only the last spinners . Remaining 3 spinners still exist. Is there anyway to remove?

Comment: I guess you should save references to your views in some List<View> and  and use it when you need.